# Met "ERROR 4: Unable to create png file D:\outPNG: Permission denied" when using createcopy to create a PNG file

Tags: gdal

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    gdal.AllRegister();
    String imgSrc = "D:\\OutImg\\subPicr6c10.TIF";
    String pngOut = "D:\\outPNG";
    Dataset tifDataset = gdal.Open(imgSrc,gdalconst.GF_Read);
    int xSize= tifDataset.getRasterXSize();
    int ySize = tifDataset.getRasterYSize();
    int nBand = tifDataset.getRasterCount();
    short[][] imgArray = new short[nBand][xSize*ySize];
    for(int i=1;i<=nBand;i++){
        Band band = tifDataset.GetRasterBand(i);
        band.ReadRaster(0,0,xSize,ySize,gdalconst.GDT_UInt16,imgArray[i-1]);
    }
    Driver memDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM");
    Dataset memDataset = memDriver.Create("",xSize,ySize,nBand,gdalconst.GDT_UInt16);
    Band pBand;
    short[][] tempArray = new short[nBand][xSize*ySize];
    for(int i=1;i<=nBand;i++){
        pBand = memDataset.GetRasterBand(i);
        pBand.WriteRaster(0,0,xSize,ySize,gdalconst.GDT_UInt16,tempArray[i-1]);
    }
    Driver pngDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName("PNG");
    Dataset pngDataset = pngDriver.CreateCopy(pngOut,memDataset);
}
```

When I use `createcopy()` and try to convert a TIF file to a PNG file,
it shows the error below. I cannot successfully create the PNG file.
I even ran as administrator, but it didn't work as well.

> ERROR 4: Unable to create png file D:\outPNG: Permission denied

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your title has more text than the body. Please [Edit] the Question to add a full problem statement to the body and clarify what "didn't work" means.

Comment: You don't have permission to write to the d drive, probably because it's a directory not a file

Comment: Specify a file + extension output? `String pngOut = "D:\\out.PNG";` or `String pngOut = "D:\\outPNG\\out.PNG";` or `String pngOut = "D:\\outIMG\\out.PNG";`

Comment: Use the `vsimem` driver instead of the `MEM` driver.  Remember to unlink (clear the memory) afterwards.